# Best way to rename a file with chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can I rename a file with chef?

In the [chef doc](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-File) I found only:

- create
- create_if_missing
- delete
- touch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use ruby_block and inside use ::File.Rename(src,dst). Chef framework doesn't have file rename (or at least didn't had until 0.10.18).

Just an example:

```
ruby_block "Rename file" do
  block do
    ::File.rename(new_resource.src,new_resource.dst)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm just wondering... Is this idempotent? I mean... What happens when this runs for a second time and `new_resource.src` doesn't exist any longer?

Comment: It will fail. This is just an example. You should assure yourself for the files from disk.

Comment: wouldn't you just put a guard?  as in `only_if { File.exists?(new_resource.src)}`

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you need to rename multiple files. Checks one of the resource to know if it already ran.

```
ruby_block "Rename file" do
  block do
    ::Dir.glob("*/*.src").each {|i| File.rename(i, i.gsub(/(.*).src/,'\\1.dst'))};
  end
  not_if {File.exists?("new_resource.dst")}
end
```