# chef - change order of process execution in /etc/rc2.d/

Tags: process, chef-infra

Note: this is not a question about *chef cookbook execution order*

I am installing nginx via `https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nginx`.

**/etc/init.d/nginx** takes care of running nginx and works.

But when I look at **/etc/rc2.d/**, I see nginx is getting started up very early (**S20nginx**).  I'd much rather start it later, because nginx depends on some other info being made available by earlier scripts.  Specifically, I may end up needing the vboxadd-xxx stuff to get at VirtualBox guest properties.

`ls /etc/rc2.d/`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 677 Mar 12  2014 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Apr 21 11:54 S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 21 11:58 S20nginx -> ../init.d/nginx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 18  2014 S20rsync -> ../init.d/rsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 18  2014 S30vboxadd -> ../init.d/vboxadd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Apr 18  2014 S30vboxadd-x11 -> ../init.d/vboxadd-x11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  25 Apr 18  2014 S35vboxadd-service -> ../init.d/vboxadd-service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Apr 18  2014 S99grub-common -> ../init.d/grub-common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 21 11:56 S99monit -> ../init.d/monit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 18  2014 S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 18  2014 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
```

So, **/etc/rc2.d/S70nginx** would be much better.

I did not find an attribute in the cookbook for the S20 bit, so I can't work with that.

Is my best bet (from [Best way to rename a file with chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528409/best-way-to-rename-a-file-with-chef)) as follows?  One brittle bit is that the *S20* is hardcoded so if the upstream cookbook changes to *S21* I will totally miss out.

Also worried that the next Chef build will think that something is missing at S20nginx and create another symlink to fix that.

```
ruby_block "re-order nginx service" do
  block do

    old_nginx_seq = '/etc/rc2.d/S20nginx'
    new_nginx_seq = '/etc/rc2.d/S70nginx'

    ::File.rename(old_nginx_seq,new_nginx_seq)

    only_if { File.exists?(old_nginx_seq)}
  end
end
```

Is there a general way to specify process startup sequence via Chef?  Perhaps with the `https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using a very old Linux distro, this is likely barking up the wrong tree. Most distros are either using Upstart or systemd, and you would control sequencing/dependencies in the relevant service config file.

Comment: Nah, trying to stay away from systemd or Upstart.  This on Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to leave my options open to switch distros if possible, including moving to AMI/CentOS.  The actual process management is mostly carried out by  a mix of `runit` and `monit`.  But thanks for this info, it helps me understand the context better.

Comment: If you are looking for unified init management in Chef, check out the poise-service cookbook (disclaimer: I wrote it).

Comment: Also as to your actual question, https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service/debian.rb is the relevant code. I think setting `priority` is probably what you want but I've purged most update-rc.d incantations from my brain because that stuff is all deeply deprecated. If moving to CentOS you have to use systemd so this won't work at all.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice.  And thanks for all the great work on the Chef cookbooks too.  One question though:  I rather like `runit` and also `monit`.  I like that runit takes away a lot of the pain of writing my own init.d script.  But, while I assume I can hook up monit to systemd, is there any point in using runit in a context where I would be using systemd as well?  Can I ignore systemd and use runit as before?

Comment: I can answer that in a few ways. 1) poise-service supports all of those as backends so you can still use a unified API 2) systemd is the future like it or not so you should probably learn it 3) monit is a cool monitoring system but a terrible init system, use it for the former not the latter.

Comment: awesome.  I had pretty much come to the same conclusion wrt 3).  Monit needs to be hooked up to something that does the start/stop/restarts on its behalf.

Comment: and, after some more testing, I think I have found a way to deal with nginx conf (bad configuration was my problem) without having it depend on something else, so for now, I'll leave the init order as is.